# I want the boolean to be set true when I click onWillPop in flutter but it not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I created two widgets and I want to change between this two in the backPress like what I do in the text field but it doesn't work and I didn't get any debug print in onWillPop.
but I have a navigation button and it connect to mainScreen page and I can change backPress in this page for all the pages but I can't do the same thing in the pages:

[image: 1]

I want to change onWillPopScope in the pages not in MainScreen

```
**//MY Page (SearchScreen)**
bool change = true;

Future<bool> _FuturePop() async {
  if (onText) {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    debugPrint("if onText => $onText");
    onText = false;
    return false;
  } else {
    debugPrint("else onText => $onText");
    return true;
  }

  // return false;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
  debugPrint("onText => $onText");
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _FuturePop,
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffEFF4F3),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //topBar
            const SpacerEmpty(),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 36,
                    child: Flexible(
                        child: TextField(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          onText = true;
                          debugPrint("onTap => $onText");
                        });
                      },
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      onEditingComplete: () {
                        onText = false;
                        debugPrint("onEdCpm => $onText");
                        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      },
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, right: 8),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  width: .5, color: Color(0xaaacacac)))),
                    )),
                  ),
                  const Positioned(
                      left: 8,
                      top: 0,
                      bottom: 0,
                      child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.search)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ...
```

**//My MainScreen Page**

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
  // if (_homeKey.currentState!.canPop()){
  //   _homeKey.currentState!.pop() ;
  // }


  if (_scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState!.closeDrawer();
    return false;
  } else if (selectedScreenIndex == homeIndex) {
    if (doubleTapedToExit) {
      return true;
    } else {
      doubleTapedToExit = true;

      ShowToast(message: 'برای خروج از برنامه دو بار دکمه بازگشت را بزنید.');

      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
        doubleTapedToExit = false;
      });
      return false;
    }
  }

  final NavigatorState currentSelectedTabNavigatorState =
      map[selectedScreenIndex]!.currentState!;
  if (currentSelectedTabNavigatorState.canPop()) {
    currentSelectedTabNavigatorState.pop();
    return false;
  } else if (_history.isNotEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      selectedScreenIndex = homeIndex;
      _history.clear();
    });
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onWillPop,
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: DrawerWidget(
            bottomNavClick: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _history.remove(selectedScreenIndex);
                _history.add(selectedScreenIndex);
                selectedScreenIndex = index;
              });
            },
            closeDrawer: () {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState!.closeDrawer();
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              bottom: 0,
              child: IndexedStack(
                index: selectedScreenIndex,
                children: [
                  _navigator(_homeKey, homeIndex, const HomeScreen()),
                  _navigator(_searchKey, searchIndex, const SearchScreen()),
                  _navigator(_addEstateKey, plusIndex, Container()),
                  _navigator(
                      _favoritesKey, favoriteIndex, const FavoriteScreen()),
                  _navigator(
                      _myEstateKey, myEstateIndex, const MyEstateScreen()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const Positioned(top: 12, right: 12, left: 12, child: _Toolbar()),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 12,
              right: 12,
              left: 12,
              child: _BottomNavigation(
                onTap: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _history.remove(selectedScreenIndex);
                    _history.add(selectedScreenIndex);
                    selectedScreenIndex = index;
                  });
                },
                selectedIndex: selectedScreenIndex,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the user to tap the back key twice to exit the app while they are on home screen.

You can see the sample code below.

```
  class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyWidget({super.key});

    @override
    State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
  }

  class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
    bool willPopScope = false;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: Container(),
      );
    }

    Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
      if (willPopScope) {
        return true;
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Press back button again to exit",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        );

        setState(() {
          willPopScope = true;
        });
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1200), () {
          setState(() {
            willPopScope = false;
          });
        });
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

You can change duration to any number according to your case.